# Magento module is not creating the database table?

Tags: magento-1.7, module, database

I am doing a module in Magento (1.7.2). In that module, I want to create a database table. I have used all the codes properly. But still, I can't see the database table in phpMyAdmin.

In `/app/etc/modules/Myfolder_Storeinfo.xml` the module info is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Myfolder_Storeinfo>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
    </Myfolder_Storeinfo>
  </modules>
</config>
```

In `IndexController.php` file inside path `/app/code/community/Myfolder/Storeinfo/controllers/IndexController.php` is like this :

```
class Myfolder_Storeinfo_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Now the module configuration file configuration XML (config.xml) the path  is `/app/code/community/Myfolder/Storeinfo/etc/config.xml` is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Myfolder_Storeinfo>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Myfolder_Storeinfo>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <storeinfo>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Myfolder_Storeinfo</module>
                    <frontName>storeinfo</frontName>
                </args>
            </storeinfo>
        </routers>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Myfolder_Storeinfo>
                    <files>
                        <default>Myfolder_Storeinfo.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Myfolder_Storeinfo>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <question>
                    <file>storeinfo.xml</file>
                </question>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <storeinfo>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Myfolder_Storeinfo</module>
                    <frontName>storeinfo</frontName>
                </args>
            </storeinfo>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <storeinfo module="storeinfo">
                <title>Storeinfo</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="storeinfo">
                        <title>Storeinfo</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>storeinfo/adminhtml_storeinfo</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </storeinfo>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Myfolder_Storeinfo>
                            <title>Storeinfo Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </Myfolder_Storeinfo>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <storeinfo>
                    <file>storeinfo.xml</file>
                </storeinfo>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>

    <global>
        <models>
            <storeinfo>
                <class>Myfolder_Storeinfo_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>storeinfo_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </storeinfo>
            <storeinfo_mysql4>
                <class>Myfolder_Storeinfo_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <storeinfo>
                        <table>Myfolder_storeinfo</table>
                    </storeinfo>
                </entities>
            </storeinfo_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <storeinfo_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Myfolder_Storeinfo</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </storeinfo_setup>
            <storeinfo_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </storeinfo_write>
            <storeinfo_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </storeinfo_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <storeinfo>
                <class>Myfolder_Storeinfo_Block</class>
            </storeinfo>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <storeinfo>
                <class>Myfolder_Storeinfo_Helper</class>
            </storeinfo>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

For creating database table my code for mysql4-install-0.1.0.php the path is `/community/MyFolder/Storeinfo/sql/storeinfo_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` is like this :

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('Myfolder_storeinfo')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('Myfolder_storeinfo')} (
  `storeinfo_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`storeinfo_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
");

$installer->endSetup();
```

But after all, I can't see my module is creating any table. From Magento admin I can see my module is enabled from `System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced->Disable Modules Output->Myfolder_Storeinfo -> enable`. So can someone kindly tell me where is the wrong part then? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

There are a few things you can check/ should do to make sure it works.

- Check in the database table `core_resources` if your extension was added and with what version
- Add a die to your installer to check if the installer is called at all
- Since `<table>Myfolder_storeinfo</table>` is the actual MySQL table name please make it lowercase

Answer (score 6):

Rename the file `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` to `install-0.1.1.php`

Delete the setup entry (for this module) in `core_resource` table

Disable the cache.

Refresh any page

Check the database

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question but I want to share this.

If you have triple checked that:

1. your module version is the right one
2. your install / data script filename is ok
3. you have really flushed the cache

Then try to **disable** all caches. I've seen a case where flushing the cache (by deleting the files or with *php cache.php destroy*) was not enough.

Disabling all caches made the module appear in the core_resource table instantly.

Answer (score 3):

Use ***storeinfo/storeinfo*** instead of ***Myfolder_storeinfo*** in mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: Could you give a bit more details for your answer, as in "why" it seems to be the best solution?

Comment: The getTable takes the group/name argument, it references to the associated setup defined in `config.xml`. Calling `getTable('storeinfo/storeinfo')` finds the `<model><storeinfo>` node, in there you have defined a reference to the `<storeinfo_resource>` node, which contains the `<entities><storeview>` node with the table name. There's not much to explain, it's simply how Magento works.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked your code on Magento CE 1.7 and it is working fine and creating a table in the database.
Please check if there is any database related issue or any write permission issue. 
You can try creating a table from phpMyAdmin and then using plain PHP and check you are able to successfully create a table.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check this condition if you are facing this type of problem.

1. `<version>0.1.1</version>` `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` // There 0.1.1 and
   -install-version(0.1.0) should be same
2. check `compilation` disable or not. In order to run installer script
   you must have to make compilation disable.
3. Check `core_resource` table and make a search on `code` column for
   your extension entry. If found then delete it
4. Delete `cache`

This steps always work for me!

Answer (score 1):

Your version is off.
config.xml has `<version>0.1.1</version>`

but your script is in `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`

Fix that then check the detail from Sander

Comment: If the version on the install file is lower than the version specified in the config file the install script should still run at first install.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. thks